# Random generated colors and saving them in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

I'm won't be able to explain this 100% because if I could I would probably figure it out.

I'm trying to code for a chat room. I want to use javascript to randomly generate a color and assign it to someone's name. But it will only assign it once and when they type a new message it defaults. How could I make it so that the color sticks? This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.username').each(function () {
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
    $(".username").css("color", hue);
}); });
```

Comment: You need to assign a specific colour to a specific user, so how do you keep track of which user posted which message? Can you show your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

try using $(this) instead of $(".username") inside your each function:

```
$('.username').each(function () {
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ',' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 200) + ')';
    $(this).css("color", hue);
});
```

Comment: Actually this will regenerate a random color for all users each time, what you really need is a unique class or ID for each user you create to keep track of what color is designated to what user..

Comment: A friend of mine mentioned adding something like username.clr_(name) in a css sheet but I had problem trying to implement that.

Comment: If you are the one coding this, I'd personally create some kind of JSON object of users and use that object to populate my needed styles.. then every time you add a user, you just add to the usersObject and initialize the properties you need, then every time he posts again, you can populate his customized styles right from the object

Comment: There's more ways to go about this but the main point you need to think about, is how do you identify each user.. once you resolve that, the rest is a breeze :)